# Win forms create a add on for a program

Tags: c#, winforms

Im not sure where to start or the correct terms for a google search hence the post here, Ive tried several searches but they all come back to creating a windows form or that area and nothing about add ons.

I am creating a program which does certain functions, I then want to create an addon to the plugin which will provide admin features to the main program.

How would I go about creating an add on and how would that interface into my main program?

Any help welcome (even if you give me the correct search terms for google).

Comment: Google search: c# plugin architecture

Comment: Thanks Ill go and research that. its always trying to find the correct term to get what you want

Comment: Sorry didnt realise it was a duplicate when posted. I used the wrong terms when I searched this site and google

Answer (score 0):

In the .net framework there is a specific section for create add-on MEF / MAF

take a look here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/dd460648%28v=vs.110%29.aspx